# How to remove item from list and return new list without removed item in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list of string as `List<String> temp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];`
I want to modify and remove specific item from the list and return new list without the removed item.

For example, if I want to remove index 2, what I want to get is `['a', 'b', 'd']`
`removeAt` doesn't work since it just returns removed string item...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation) to return the list when you call `removeAt`.

```dart
void main() {
  print(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']..removeAt(2));
}
```

Comment: thanks - this is what I wanted. Do you know why cascade notation allows us to return original list instead removed string?

Comment: Cascade basically just returns the object you operate on, instead of the return value from the method call.

Comment: as someone who's currently learning Dart, I'm a little confused as to why this is necessary...? the [`List.removeAt()` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.0/dart-core/List/removeAt.html) directly modifies the list that it operates on.. so in the context of this question, after calling `temp.removeAt(2)`, the list in `temp` quite literally **is** the "new list without the removed item".  or (as a Dart noob) am I missing something here?

Comment: @AndreGreeff `temp.removeAt(2)` returns `'c'`, while `temp..removeAt(2)` returns `['a', 'b', 'd']`. But yes, `temp` will store `['a', 'b', 'd']` regardless.

Comment: ah, so I guess the "difference" between the two in this case is mostly just convenience then..? thanks @mmcdon20

Answer (score 7):

`temp.removeAt(index);` is exactly what you want.

```
void main() {
  List<String> temp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  temp.removeAt(2);
  print(temp);
}
```

this function prints `['a', 'b', 'd']` which is what you wanted to get right?

but if you can also get the removed value with this.

```
void main() {
  List<String> temp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  var removedValue = temp.removeAt(2);
  print(removedValue);
}
```

If what you want is to get a clone of the original list but without the element you can create a new one like this.

```
  void main() {
  List<String> temp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  int indexToRemove = 2;
  List newList = temp.where((x) => temp.indexOf(x) != indexToRemove).toList();
  print(newList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove items with logic you can also check out the code below this will help you to remove items with conditions.

```
List<String> temp = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];

for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
  if(temp[i] == "Mon") {
    temp.removeAt(i);
 }
}
```